# my logo image isnt showing up properly in Html

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="logo-wrapper">
  <img src="images/Logos/button-1.png > 
</div>
```

[image]
I have added a picture to so you can see exactly what I did. Help would be deeply appreciated

Comment: check back your image file path

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `div` tag isn't closed and you forgot the quotes at the end of the image path:

```
<div class="logo-wrapper"> 
    <img src="images/Logos/button-1.png" > 
</div>
```

2. Your image path might be wrong